# Android Multi screen background

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to set the [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image attached below as my layouts background.It looks good on few device backgrounds and few devices shows consecutive circles in center which makes the UI inconsistent. I want consistent over all the device densities. How can I achieve the UI appearance on all devices being consistent?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you mean.the grammar is a little bit unclear.do you mean the same background for all layouts?

Comment: I have facing a problem to render the attached image  into background for layout. The problem is that the image shows successive circles due the radiant glow at center. Centered gradient glow shows circles on few devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create versions of the 9Patch png for each density and put them in the relevant drawable folders (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc).

When you run your app, android determines the screen density of the device you're running it on and then looks in that particular drawable folder for your 9Patch png. If it can't find a 9Patch png in the folder for that density, it will look in the folders for the other densities until it does find one. It will then either stretch or compress the png as needed to try and create a suitable png for the missing density. This stretching and compressing can lead to the sort of artifacts you are seeing.

For best results, don't leave it up to the operating system to try and generate images for missing screen densities. Provide your own images for each density.

Below is an excerpt from [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) on the Android Developers site. Take the time to read and understand this if you want to progress with developing apps for android, because this is fundamental to designing the look of any UI.

"..you should start with your raw resource in vector format and generate the images for each density using the following size scale:

xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
ldpi: 0.75

This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for mdpi, and 75x75 for ldpi devices."

Comment: Did this not answer the question?